# Could not find a configuration file for package

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,there:
i am following "kobuki/Tutorials/Write your own controller for Kobuki" to write an nodelet，In CMakelists.txt,it called function:find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS kobuki_msgs nodelet roscpp std_msgs yocs_controllers)，But it comes a ERROR: Could not find a configuration file for package kobuki_msgs. Set kobuki_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file  for kobuki_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:    kobuki_msgsConfig.cmake    kobuki_msgs-config.cmake.
but the question is that in kobuki_msgs, there is no .camke file. And i also found that packages in ros/groovy/share all contains a corresponding .cmake file, while in ros/groovy/stacks did not. but the kobuki_msgs package is located in ros/groovy/stacks.
so what can i do? is anyone else encounter this ERROR?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98631/could-not-find-a-configuration-file-for-package/) by [zhongjin616](https://answers.ros.org/users/8531/zhongjin616/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-11-06**:
The error should be that you are asking catkin to find a rosbuild package (in fact kobuki_msgs is in the /stacks folder). You should remove kobuki_msgs from the line find_package() in your CMakeLists.txt, but I don't know if this will be enough to solve the problem. Let me know!

**Comment by [zhongjin616](https://answers.ros.org/users/8531/zhongjin616/) on 2013-11-07**:
thanks for your advise. I do remove kobuki_msgs from the find_package(), and truely the CMake did not warn me that cannot find a configuration file for package kobuki_msgs. but it does not fix my problem , as i do need kobuki_msgs.today ,i download a catkin_version of kobuki_msgs,problem solved.ThX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I made a little research and i found out what I already suspected: Catkin packages cannot depend on rosbuild packages! (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild)

So the only solution I think you have is to create the package with rosbuild and not with catkin. The strange thing is that the tutorial should be valid from groovy on, but if you have the rosbuild version of kobuki_msgs, this won't work... Anyway I also found this link where to download the rosbuild version of the tutorial I think you are talking about. Hope this will be useful!

https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/tree/groovy/kobuki_controller_tutorial

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhongjin616](https://answers.ros.org/users/8531/zhongjin616/) on 2013-11-07**:
yes，i download the catkin_version of kobuki_msgs, and catkin_make it. the problem fix. So thanks for you sharing,it do help me a lot.